# Electron js Multiples errores en la consola

Tags: javascript, electron

Hola tengo un problema o varios mejor dicho estoy usando electron para crear una app de una web y me estan saltando estos errores al reproducir un video y al navegar entre las paginas ademas se traba mucho la app

```
este es mi codigo

const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')


let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})


win.loadURL("https://www.google.com")



[19380:1117/212101.599:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212101.600:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.606:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.606:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.609:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.626:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.652:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.658:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.672:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.693:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.703:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.724:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.729:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.754:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.758:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.759:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.772:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.785:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.788:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.788:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.790:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212107.791:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility
[19380:1117/212147.644:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:61007 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.645:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:61008 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.645:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:61011 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.645:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:61012 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.646:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57278 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.683:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57279 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.723:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57282 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.738:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57283 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.746:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:61007 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.747:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:61008 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.748:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:61011 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.749:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:61012 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.757:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57278 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.861:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57279 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.897:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57282 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.945:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57283 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.946:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57286 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.949:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57286 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.960:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57287 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.996:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57287 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.998:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57290 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.998:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57290 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212147.999:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57291 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212147.999:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57291 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.014:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57294 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.032:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57294 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.033:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57295 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.065:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57295 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.067:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57298 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.129:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57298 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.161:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57299 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.161:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57299 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.165:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57302 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.199:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57302 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.210:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57303 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.277:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57303 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.279:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57306 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.315:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 192.168.56.x:57306 ({0A4DCAED-B408-4C5A-BFCA-9C454C635CE3})
[19380:1117/212148.330:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57307 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
[19380:1117/212148.359:ERROR:stun_port.cc(93)] Binding request timed out from 26.50.184.x:57307 ({C45C311C-0FEE-4B8F-917E-EB23E0E72403})
```

tienen idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Te invito a leer [mcve]. En cuanto a tu pregunta: ***¿tienen idea de que puede estar pasando?***, la verdad que con lo que aportas, es imposible saber lo que está pasando. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras segun veo en la cosola solo me salta ese error nunca me salto ese tipo de error antes es la primera ves

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `electron` estás usando y bajo qué sistema operativo?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Electron 6.0.12, OS windows 10

Comment: El error viene dado por este código... en C++: https://github.com/maojie/webrtc/blob/master/pc/data_channel.cc

Comment: @PabloLozano y como lo soluciono mi codigo es solo lo que esta puesto arriba no tengo nada mas

Comment: @MauricioContreras Quizás reinstalando _Electron_ o _Webkit_ o usando una versión más antigua se soluciona. Debe ser un problema de compatibilidad entre versiones.